# Yii2 выдаёт ошибку при обращении к методу модели, ищет не модель, а метод контроллера

Tags: yii2, классы

Я обращаюсь к экшену контроллера и пытаюсь из него вызвать метод класса модели. При этом выскакивает ошибка "Class 'app\controllers\SheduleTrip' not found". Ведь я же прописал "use app\models\ScheduleTrip;". То есть класс должен находиться в моделях, а не контроллерах. Но он его не видит.
Вот что написано в коде контроллера:

namespace app\controllers;

use Yii;

use app\models\Order;

use app\models\OrderSearch;

use yii\web\Controller;

use yii\web\ForbiddenHttpException;

use yii\web\NotFoundHttpException;

use yii\filters\VerbFilter;

use app\components\Helper;

use app\models\Trip;

use app\models\Direction;

**use app\models\ScheduleTrip;**

...

public function actionSetTrips($shedule_id=1){

```
var_dump(SheduleTrip::getSheduleTripListByShedule($shedule_id));


return 123;
```

}

Answer (score 0):

В методе указан класс с ошибкой в один символ `c`

Должно быть не SheduleTrip а S**c**heduleTrip, если в `use` указано верно.

А так как этого класса нет в `use`, то php пытается найти его в директории текущего класса.

Рекомендую работать в среде разработки, например PhpStorm, она бы вам сразу всё подсказала.